# Multiple receiving address on exchanges

Tags: transactions, address-generation

If I have 0.01 on an exchange that allows generating new addresses , and I send 0.02 to a new address on that exchange , and then I send 0.025 off of that exchange , did I basically cross spend and the new address with 0.005, and the other 2 addresses , are now all traceable to be connected to each other?  To my understanding because transactions have many digits, they can be used to map the addresses (.010122+.024991=...do math with mining fees..==> ok these 3 are making this transaction)

For complete privacy and annonymity would I need to first empty out the account first ?  I would end up with a lot of dust.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange services will generally consolidate customer deposits, and allow withdrawals from a communal hot-wallet. So the coins you receive upon withdrawal may have very little on-chain relation to the coins you deposited. The specifics of this will vary from one exchange to another though.

> For complete privacy and anonymity would I need to first empty out the account first ? I would end up with a lot of dust.

Bitcoin [can be used privately](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103243/63872), but it takes some work. Emptying out your account won't do much, and if you're looking for privacy, then you shouldn't be transacting through a trusted third party anyways.

Comment: If I take out that it was on an exchange , and say I do this on Electrum , are the 2 original addresses and 1 address with the remaining amount traceable to each other ?

Comment: Yes, but not because of the output's values as your question suggested, it would simply be because all the inputs/outputs in question were party to the same transaction. See for example: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy#Common-input-ownership_heuristic